Is this a Java bug or am I misusing Java (preview)'s structured task scope?
So I have this code excerpt (a minimal reproduction, from a much larger project, and blocking issue). It leverages Java 22 (preview)'s structured task scope in  combo with virtual threads:
playground.java
void main() throws InterruptedException {
  final var NAME = ScopedValue.<String>newInstance();
  try (var ts = new StructuredTaskScope<>()) {
    ScopedValue.runWhere(NAME, "haha", () -> {
      ts.fork(() -> {
   // ^^^
   // java.util.concurrent.StructureViolationException: Scoped value bindings have changed
        return null;
      });
    });
    ts.join();
  }
}

Using Java 22, you can run it with java --enable-preview --source 22 playground.java.

You are using the structured task scope wrong.
The JavaDoc for StructuredTaskScope.fork() states:

StructureViolationExceptionPREVIEW - if the current scoped value bindings are not the same as when the task scope was created

Your code changes the scoped value bindings by calling ScopedValue.runWhere(NAME, "haha", () -> {}); after the task scope was created.
You should probably structure your code like this:
void main() throws InterruptedException {
  final var NAME = ScopedValue.<String>newInstance();
  ScopedValue.runWhere(NAME, "haha", () -> {
    try (var ts = new StructuredTaskScope<>()) {
      ts.fork(() -> {
        return null;
      });
    });
    ts.join();
  }
}

Or you can create a new task scope after changing the scoped value:
void main() throws InterruptedException {
  final var NAME = ScopedValue.<String>newInstance();
  try (var ts = new StructuredTaskScope<>()) {
    ScopedValue.runWhere(NAME, "haha", () -> {
      try (var ts2 = new StructuredTaskScope<>()) {
        ts2.fork(() -> {
          return null;
        });
        ts2.join();
      }
    });
    ts.join();
  }
}


Please don't use 'in my humble opinion' when this is all highly objective and not at all subjective. Your code is right, OP's code is wrong. They're asking on SO, I don't think they mind creating the impression that their code has some issues :) – Other than that aggravating style faux pas, a fine answer!

Of course, you can also create new scopes within the sub scope, i.e. call ScopedValue.runWhere(…) within the forked task. The only thing you can’t do, is forking a task of the outer scope within the inner scope.

Or, to show that it also works with one StructuredTaskScope (where the crucial point is to change the value after forking, within the forked subtask): try(var ts = new StructuredTaskScope<>()) { ts.fork(() -> ScopedValue.callWhere(NAME, "haha\n", () -> System.out.append(NAME.get()))); ts.fork(() -> ScopedValue.callWhere(NAME, "other\n", () -> System.out.append(NAME.get()))); ts.join(); }

The accepted answer addressed my question for understanding but I'm stuck with the other one... Because the value I want to scope is not a String but that specific StructuredTaskScope (so that nested threads can fork within the same task scope).

@SalathielGenese I'm not sure what you mean with but that specific StructuredTaskScope. I don't think you can store a StructuredTaskScope in a ScopedValue. But you can either pass the StructuredTaskScope as parameter to other methods or you can created nested StructuredTaskScope objects (see the second example in my answer). If you need something else then please ask a new question with an example of what you want.

Thank you @ThomasKläger for following up. It took me some time but I addressed it with thre levels of indirections. 1. the scoped value is a function that matches the fork method. 2. the outer structured task scope (STS) set the value of that function to an atomic ref of STS. 3. The value of that atomic ref is set to the inner STS. It addressed my issue. Thank you again, Thomas.

@SalathielGenese the whole point of StructuredTaskScope is to support clearly nested task scopes. It’s not clear to me, what advantage you expect to gain from shoehorning a scenario that doesn’t fit into this. For your scenario, the result will not be better than using, e.g.  Executors.newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor() in the first place.

@Holger, I agree. I'm implementing Java Flow API, which must pass reactive-strream TCK. I'm trying to have it backed up by virtual threads. BUT... I want the API designed like RxJS (not RxJava nor Project Reactor which both have a limitation on custom operators). NEXT... I find out some operators like flatMap may start their own producer and would need to start threads on the same structured task scope (STS). FINALLY, that is where scoped values come in handy to share value in the IoC thread-safe manner PS: I want the fork method exposed but not the STS itself. https://imgur.com/carbon-r1cAbOS
